# (node:2407) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Upon trying to send user data for registration, the app returns the (node:2407) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas error. It seems that I am having problems with the connection string of MongoDB but I am also not sure. I am using React/Redux for my front-end and Node.js for my backend.

I have tried replacing the connection strings over to different alternative, but it seems to not be working. As I see from another post, it seems I need to pick the longer connection strings, which unfortunately I cannot find in MongoDB Atlas website.

Below is my connection string code:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI:
    "mongodb+srv://willy123:willy123@devconnector-cddgi.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true",
  secretOrKey: "secret"
};
```

Below I have authActions.js that returns authActions return err.response = undefined after I submit the data.

```
import { GET_ERRORS } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

I want to know how to solve this issue so that I can successfully send data to my MongoDB database.

Comment: post your code for `/api/users/register`

Comment: Sorry I fixed it already. Apparently Atlas changed their UI and I need to downgrade the Node.js to version 2.1.2 or lower to get it working. Thank you for trying to help! :)